# WPF textbox validation client side

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I am did text box validation.

But i want to make some style on text box on various phase.

When my page 1st time load the textbox looks like following style.
[image]

When User start entering value and if value is wrong the entire textbox background will be RED. 
[image]

When user enter right value the Text box have GREEN Border with 2PX.
[image]

I am Using Following Style  :

```
  <Style x:Key="TxtEmailStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2d2f34"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                        Foreground="Orange"
                        FontSize="12pt">
                        !!!!
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#56585e" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#07839a" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#cb0b38"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <!--<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2d2f34"></Setter>
            </Trigger>-->

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The following is my TextBox

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtPlayerID"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Style="{StaticResource TxtEmailStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="228" FontFamily="Arial Regular"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.408,-2.455" FontSize="14"
                                     Margin="27,0,0,0">

                                <TextBox.Text>

                                    <Binding Path="playerID" Source="{StaticResource Register}"
                          ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"     NotifyOnValidationError="True"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>

                                            <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
```

Comment: What is the question you did it or you want to do it ?

Comment: @ Shrivallabh :  I want to change the TextBox border style on base of the user input :- if Correct input Make it Green   , If Wrong input Background Red  , and if no input then default textbox style

Comment: You can show your `dependency property` which has `playerID` ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Assuming your viewmodel is bound up correctly and is correctly validating the property associated with the textbox, it should work correctly.  Your styles are a bit of a mess though, I would remove those completely if it were me

Answer (score 0):

A tricky/ugly approach is to use a story board (might be tricky, as you don't want animation, but you can change the animation time to infinite anyway) below is the code snippet:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ChangeBkColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Background)">
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
             From="Red" To="Red" Duration="0:0:10"/> <!--Change 10 secs to yours-->
</Storyboard>
```

And somewhere, e.g. in the text changed event handler

```
Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("ChangeBkColor") as Storyboard;
if (sb != null && SomeCondition1)  <!--SomeCondition1: for red background-->
{
     Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, this.txtPlayerID);
     sb.Begin();  // Here comes the effect!
}
```

You should create two story boards for your case, and in the text changed handler, tell what conditions, and selectively play the story boards.